# VBA Excel run javascript form event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, vba

I’ve already tried to get the element by id, however, the html does not include it. As shown below, this is the script for the drop down that I am trying to change automatically. It will change the name with

`appIE.Document.getElementById("supervisor").Value = "Sup_name"`

However, it doesn’t fire the event that generates a list of people.

The top of the form also includes `<form id='filterform' action="javascript:void(0);">`

The JavaScript containing the function I need to call is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#supervisor').change(function() {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<img src="/img/busy.gif" />';
            var str = $('#filterform').serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php?p=agentrosters&mode=1&field=supervisor',
                type: 'POST',
                data: str,
                success: function(j) {
                    //alert(j);
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = j;
                    document.getElementById('lastsearch').value = 'supervisor';
                    resetscript('supervisor');
                },
                failure: function() {
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'There has been an error, please try again';
                    resetscript('null');
                }
            })
        })
    })

</script>
```

Any Ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Try `appIE.Document.getElementById("supervisor").change()` or `appIE.Document.getElementById("supervisor").Firevent("onchange")`

Comment: I tried both but neither one worked. The first one gave me an error "expecting ="

Comment: Typo - `.Firevent("onchange")` >> `.FireEvent("onchange")`

Comment: Even with the typo corrected it still did not properly fire the JavaScript event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is part of a form you may to submit the form, alternatively you can use the onchange event on the element itself. So you may want to change

`appIE.Document.getElementById("supervisor").Value = "Sup_name"`

to

`With appIE.document.getElementById("supervisor")
.Value = "Sup_name"
.onchange
End with`

And if it is part of a form change the ".onchange" to 
".parentElement.Submit"

This worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct Javascript syntax? This link suggests otherwise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with